# Natural Transformation Conditions

Tags: category-theory

What conditions i have to satisfy for showing natural transformation? Just to show that the diagram is commutative or something else? I need to show that the composition of two natural transformation is again natural transformation.

Comment: do you know the definition of natural transformation?

Comment: Wikipedia is helpful.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Operations_with_natural_transformations

Comment: Which composition? (There are two type of compositions for natural transformations.) What have you tried? Show us your thoughts.